# Flutter - How to get my data variable's DateFormat and change timezone

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am getting dates for a project through an API. The dates are in the format `2022-09-04T13:00:00+00:00` and I want to format this into two different variables - one that holds the date formatted as `September 04, 2022` and one that holds the time formatted as `13:00`. It has to be formatted with respect to the device's current timezone, but my issue is that I don't know which format the original date is in as I can't find what to write for the `+00:00` part.

Since the date seems to be in UTC, I was thinking of a solution like below (based on other SO questions).

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

// I need the correct format on the following line instead of +XX:XX
var dateValue = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+XX:XX").parseUTC("2022-09-04T13:00:00+00:00").toLocal();

String formattedDate = DateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm").format(dateValue);
String formattedTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(dateValue);
```

Suggestions on better ways to do this are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `Z` can represent the entire timezone in the formats, so the following solution works.

```
  import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

  var date = "2022-09-04T13:00:00+00:00";

  var dateValue = DateFormat('yyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ').parseUTC(date).toLocal();

  String formattedDate = DateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(dateValue);
  String formattedTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(dateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it as a `DateTime` directly, at which Dart will *per default* recognize the +00:00 as timezone and interpret that as UTC.

To get the DateTime with respect to device current timezone, append the `.toLocal()` on the `DateTime` object, and format it as you please.

```
final incomingDate = '2022-09-04T13:00:00+00:00';
final dateValue = DateTime.parse(incomingDate); // dateValue.isUtc == true
final formatted1 = DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm').format(dateValue.toLocal());
```

Check this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f23a2af22eb295433467a9c4f65f4434), and you can see examples.

Answer (score 0):

For date format, you can use `DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_US')` it will shows the date as `September 04, 2022` .
For time format, you can use `DateFormat.Hm()` so it will shows the time as `17:08 // force 24 hour time` and `DateFormat.jm()` shows `5:08 PM`.

Please read the documentaiton [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)